# How to retrieve current cest name in codeception?

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I want to use the cest name in my tests, but are not able to retrieve it.
According to the [codeception documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Current-values), it is possible to retrieve the function name. This is working for me:

```php
 public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I, \Codeception\Scenario $scenario) {
        codecept_debug($scenario->current("name")); // outputs tryToTest

}
```

How can the cest class name be retrieved similarly? It would be best, if does not need to hack with something like `get_class($this)`. I want to use the cest name in helpers also.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. With hooks in the helper class and the descriptor class, one can generate unique test identifiers, which look much like what I am looking for. The correct key for the question seems to be `env`.

```php
    public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test) {
        $id = \Codeception\Test\Descriptor::getTestSignatureUnique($test);
        codecept_debug($id);
    }
```